# Cant get .append to output to "body"

Tags: jquery

I have this as my code, but I cannot get it to output. It should be outputting to

```
var guestList = [{
    name: "Alex",
    address: "283 Happy Lane"
}, {
    name: "Avery",
    address: "32 Skippy Skip"
}, {
    name: "Pat",
    address: "666 Heaven St."
}, {
    name: "Bobbie",
    address: "83 Quality St."
}, {
    name: "Parker",
    address: "92 Batty Bat"
}];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (pointer = 0; pointer < guestList.length; pointer++) {
        labelHtml =
            "<div class='label'>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].name + "</p>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].address + "</p>" + "</div>";
        $("body").append(labelHtml);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is flagged with jquery-mobile. Don't use `$(document).ready()` in this context. pageinit or pageshow should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me which leads me to ask you two silly questions :

- Have you included jQuery on the page ?
- Do you have a stylesheet rule preventing the list
  items or list from being displayed ?

I'm sorry but It can only be one of these 2 things.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections:

- It's always safe to use .ready() function in the beginning of the script
- `pointer` variable is not defined.
- Your not appending it instead your assigning it to the variable `labelHtml`.

**Updated script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var guestList = [
    {
        name: "Alex",
        address: "283 Happy Lane"
    }, {
        name: "Avery",
        address: "32 Skippy Skip"
    }, {
        name: "Pat",
        address: "666 Heaven St."
    }, {
        name: "Bobbie",
        address: "83 Quality St."
    }, {
        name: "Parker",
        address: "92 Batty Bat"
    }];

    for (var pointer = 0; pointer < guestList.length; pointer++) {
        labelHtml +=
            "<div class='label'>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].name + "</p>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].address + "</p>" + "</div>";
        $("body").append(labelHtml);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works! See here: http://jsfiddle.net/c7W7C/

Did you include jQuery correctly? Try:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had that in there. I changed
$("body").append(labelHtml);
to
$("#body").append(labelHtml);
and then had the output in
<div id="body"></div>
and all of a sudden it worked...

Comment: If you had jquery included correctly the only other possibility why it wouldn't work with `$("body")` (to place it within the `<body>` tag) would be some css rule, that prevents the elements from being displayed. If you want to keep investigating you could check if the elements are appended to the <body> with the inspector (cmd+alt+i in chrome) and check what css styles apply.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using jquery-mobile** you shouldn't use `$(document).ready()`, since jqm is loading pages with ajax and it's not guaranteed that `$(document).ready()` is working properly in this context. See [JQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) on this.

Try `.on('pageinit'...)` or maybe `.on('pageshow'...)` instead (whatever fits your needs):

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    var guestList = [
    {
        name: "Alex",
        address: "283 Happy Lane"
    }];

    for (var pointer = 0; pointer < guestList.length; pointer++) {
        labelHtml +=
            "<div class='label'>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].name + "</p>" + "<p>" + guestList[pointer].address + "</p>" + "</div>";
        $("body").append(labelHtml);
    }
});
```

maybe you have to enhance the content after adding it to the dom.